# cannot insert null value in id column

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data into `medicine` + `Stock` tables.

But it through an error cannot insert null value into column id table `medicalstore.dbo.stock`

Here are my queries:

```
query = "Insert Into Medicine (Code,Name,CompanyID,UnitPrice,CategoryID) Values ('" & row.Cells("MedCode").Value & "','" & row.Cells("MedName").Value & "','" & row.Cells("MedCompID").Value & "','" & row.Cells("MedPrice").Value & "','" & row.Cells("MedCatID").Value & "')"
query1 =   "Insert Into Stock(MedicineID,AvailableQuantity) Values('2338','10')"
```

Here is my table structure.

```
Create table medicine
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ExpiryDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [ID_Medicine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MedicineID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AvailableQuantity] [bigint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [Stock_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Stock_Medicine] FOREIGN KEY([MedicineID])
      REFERENCES [dbo].[Medicine] ([ID])
)
```

Here is what I get when I enter `StockID` by myself

[image: Here is what I get when I enter StockID by myself]

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `Not Null` in stock Table

```
[ID] [int] NOT NULL
```

Then You have to Specify its ID while inserting and Single Quotes is not need for Integers

```
query1 =   "Insert Into Stock(ID,MedicineID,AvailableQuantity) Values(1,2338,10)"
```

or

You can Change table Definition Something Like This

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stock](
[ID] [int] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MedicineID] [int] NOT NULL,
[AvailableQuantity] [bigint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Stock_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Stock_Medicine] FOREIGN KEY([MedicineID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Medicine] ([ID])
)
```

then try like this:

```
 query1 =   "Insert Into Stock(MedicineID,AvailableQuantity) Values(2338,10)"
```

Comment: Thanks. let me see that

Comment: @CodyMan did you check `ID=2338 ` is present in table `medicine`??

Comment: Nope its not present.

Comment: I'm assigning id to a variable using this query.

"Select IsNULL(Max(ID+1), 0) ID from Medicine"
Then i'm using "Insert Into Stock(id,MedicineID,AvailableQuantity) Values(1,'" & id & "','" & quantity & "')"

Comment: @Hence You need to first insert `ID=2338` into stock medicine table then fire `query1 =   "Insert Into Stock(ID,MedicineID,AvailableQuantity) Values(1,2338,10)"` because you set for `FOREIGN ` key

Comment: For your information what i'm doing is adding value to Medicine table then i'm fetching medicine max id from table using
`Select IsNULL(Max(ID+1), 0) ID from Medicine`
then i'm assigning id to stock id

Comment: @CodyMan it means you are inserting medicine id into stock table which is not present in medicine table

Comment: it is present because first i'm adding medicine table data then stock

Comment: @CodyMan change `Select IsNULL(Max(ID+1), 0) as ID` to this `Select IsNULL(Max(ID), 0) as ID`

Answer (score 0):

You should either insert the Stock.ID yourself or specify `IDENTITY(1,1)`  for Stock.ID

Comment: While i'm trying to add stock id by my self having some foreign key error

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Stock_Medicine". The conflict occurred in database "MedicalStore", table "dbo.Medicine", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That clearly says the provided Stock.MedicineId has no match in Medicine.Id

Comment: I'm assigning id to a variable using this query. "Select IsNULL(Max(ID+1), 0) ID from Medicine" Then i'm using "Insert Into Stock(id,MedicineID,AvailableQuantity) Values(1,'" & id & "','" & quantity & "')"